# Autowiring xml bean into @Configuration Class

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations, autowired

I use generally xml configuration in my Spring project under the three files:

**applicationContext.xml:**
This file contains the main xml configuration: component scan, annotation-config and also an include of two other xml configuration files:

**applicationContext-db.xml**
This file contains all database beans: dataSource, SessionFactory, ...

**applicationContext-security.xml** 
This file contains all spring security config.

I need to use also Spring Security ACL, for this I created a configuration class:

**AclMethodSecurityConfiguration.java**

```
package com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.conf;

/**
/* all imports goes here.
**/

@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:conf/applicationContext-db.xml"})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class AclMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler defaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        AclPermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator = new AclPermissionEvaluator(aclService());
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        return expressionHandler;
    }


    @Bean
    public JdbcMutableAclService aclService() {
        return new JdbcMutableAclService(dataSource, lookupStrategy(), aclCache());
    }

    @Bean
    public AclAuthorizationStrategy aclAuthorizationStrategy() {
        return new AclAuthorizationStrategyImpl(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }


    @Bean
    public PermissionGrantingStrategy permissionGrantingStrategy() {
        return new DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy(new ConsoleAuditLogger());
    }


    @Bean
    public EhCacheBasedAclCache aclCache() {
        return new EhCacheBasedAclCache(
                    aclEhCacheFactoryBean().getObject(),
                    permissionGrantingStrategy(),
                    aclAuthorizationStrategy()
                    );
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheFactoryBean aclEhCacheFactoryBean() {
        EhCacheFactoryBean ehCacheFactoryBean = new EhCacheFactoryBean();
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheManager(aclCacheManager().getObject());
        ehCacheFactoryBean.setCacheName("aclCache");
        return ehCacheFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean aclCacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public LookupStrategy lookupStrategy() {
        return new BasicLookupStrategy(
                    dataSource,
                    aclCache(),
                    aclAuthorizationStrategy(),
                    new ConsoleAuditLogger());
    }
}
```

My problem is the datasource autowired into Configuration file is null, I don't kwno if i missed something.

My XMLs files are all under: src/main/resources/conf/

There is my datasource bean definition in applicationContext-db.xml

```
<!--        DATASOURCE                      -->
<bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
</bean>
```

I already used this bean into Sessionfactory bean defined in the same applicationContext-db.xml file.

*PS: When I remove the extended class `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` my datasource is defined, but I need this `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration`class to set up my Spring Security ACL configuration.*

Comment: Is your `com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist.conf` available for component scan? I mean does spring able to find your configuration class to inject Datasource?

Comment: Yes I use: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist"/>`  in my applicationContext.xml

Comment: Can you try it without classpath? Like as `{"conf/applicationContext-db.xml"}`

Comment: No by using your proposition I get: `IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/conf/applicationContext-db.xml];`

Comment: Can u put full log file? It is not able to find given file or not able to parse it?

Comment: Or we can try `{"classpath:/conf/applicationContext-db.xml"}`

Comment: I think not able to find file:  `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/conf/applicationContext-db.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/conf/applicationContext-db.xml]`

Comment: @Vasif same issue with `{"classpath:/conf/applicationContext-db.xml"}`: datasource null

Comment: With my IDE (Intellij) using `{"classpath:/conf/applicationContext-db.xml"}` it create me a link to my file even with `{"classpath*:conf/applicationContext-db.xml"}`

Comment: Can u share your Datasource bean definition from `applicationContext-db.xml`
PS: you can replace username/password with *

Comment: @Vasif I updated my post adding datasource bean definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to define my datasource bean by using the `BeanFactoryAware` interface.
BeanFactoryAware is used to inject the BeanFactory object. This way we get access to the BeanFactory which created the object.

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:/conf/applicationContext-db.xml"})
public class AclMethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {

    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.dataSource = beanFactory.getBean("dataSource", DataSource.class);
    }
    // rest of code goes here 
}
```

I read that if we use this technic that means we are doing something wrong, I'll continue searching for a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please rename your bean as `name="dataSource"`

Comment: I renamed it but it doesn't resolve my problem, my datasource always null.

Comment: Can we try without extending `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration `? Just keep your Java config simple, to check problem step by step. I can't see any other problem, only it maybe depency order problem while you extending from other config file

Comment: Yes by removing the extended class my datasource is defined (I got another issues) but my datasource is defined.

Comment: Also, main point. Did you added annotation config as well? `<context:annotation-config/>` ?

Comment: So, do u still need help to solve it after removing out extend? Maybe you can add this @autowire datasource to your parent class?

Comment: Yes I still need help because the parent class is a `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration;` class, I can't change it and I need it to set up my Spring Security ACL configuration.

Comment: Lets try hard coded component scan. Could you please add below line to your Config?
`@ComponentScan("com.medkhelifi.tutorials.todolist")`

Comment: No it didn't resolve the problem, But I think I found a track to set up datasource, I check it and I post a response.